# In Unity3D, activate phone camera when tilting phone

Tags: mobile, unity-game-engine, camera, tilt-sensor

we are working in an Unity game for mobile.
Basically it is a scene with 3D characters and a map to see where they are.
I would like to know how can I activate the phone camera when I tilt vertically the phone to see the 3D characters inserted in the real world,
and return to a map view of the 3D world when I tilt it horizontally. Any ideas if it is possible?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check in Script in the Update Function you can put Something like this:

```
using UnityEngine.UI;

    public Image image;

    void Update()
    {
    if (Input.deviceOrientation == DeviceOrientation.FaceDown)
        image.gameObject.SetActive(true);
    }
    else
   {
        image.gameObject.SetActive(false);
   }
```

And in the Image you should add an Script with this content:

```
void Start ()
     {
             plane = GameObject.FindWithTag ("Player");

             mCamera = new WebCamTexture ();
             plane.renderer.material.mainTexture = mCamera;
             mCamera.Play ();

     }
```